# Get index count in terraform dynamic block

Tags: terraform

Tell me, please, How can I get the iteration index in a dynamic block when iterating over an object?
I need to replace 0 with index to get different passwords for different users.

```
resource "random_password" "pwd" {
  count = length(var.users)
  length           = 18
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%@"
}

resource "yandex_mdb_postgresql_cluster" "mdb_postgres" {

  dynamic "user" {
    for_each = var.users
    content {
      name       = user.value.name
      password   = user.value.password == "" || user.value.password == null ? random_password.pwd[0].result : user.value.password
    }
  }
}
```

The user is an object

```
variable "users" {
  type = map(object({
    name       = string
    password   = string
    conn_limit = number
    permissions = list(object({
      database_name = string
    }))
  }))
 }
```

Comment: Why not use `for_each` fot the `random_password` as well?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you provide some little example?)

Comment: I tried to run plan but unfortunately the Yandex cloud requires credentials which I don't have and you have omitted a big chunk of the required configuration for the PostgreSQL resource, so let me know if the answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each` in the `yandex_mdb_postgresql_cluster` resource, the same logic can be used in the case of the password creation. That way a `random_password` resource with the same key names as in the second resource will be created. Here's a working example:

```
resource "random_password" "pwd" {
  for_each         = var.users
  length           = 18
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%@"
}

variable "users" {
  type = map(object({
    name       = string
    password   = string
    conn_limit = number
    permissions = list(object({
      database_name = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

For a `terraform.tfvars` file with the following values:

```
users = {
  "marko" = {
    conn_limit = 1
    name       = "marko"
    password   = "pass123"
    permissions = [{
      database_name = "dbname"
    }]
  },
  "valeriy" = {
    conn_limit = 1
    name       = "valeriy"
    password   = "pass456"
    permissions = [{
      database_name = "dbname1"
    }]
  }
}
```

it will create two elements with keys that correspond to the keys in the `users` variable:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_password.pwd["marko"] will be created
  + resource "random_password" "pwd" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + length           = 18
      + lower            = true
      + min_lower        = 0
      + min_numeric      = 0
      + min_special      = 0
      + min_upper        = 0
      + number           = true
      + override_special = "_!%@"
      + result           = (sensitive value)
      + special          = true
      + upper            = true
    }

  # random_password.pwd["valeriy"] will be created
  + resource "random_password" "pwd" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + length           = 18
      + lower            = true
      + min_lower        = 0
      + min_numeric      = 0
      + min_special      = 0
      + min_upper        = 0
      + number           = true
      + override_special = "_!%@"
      + result           = (sensitive value)
      + special          = true
      + upper            = true
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

random_password.pwd["valeriy"]: Creating...
random_password.pwd["marko"]: Creating...
random_password.pwd["valeriy"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=none]
random_password.pwd["marko"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=none]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Take note of the key in the square brackets, e.g.: `random_password.pwd["valeriy"]`.

This means you can now reference the password in the second resource by using the key name from the `users` variable:

```
resource "yandex_mdb_postgresql_cluster" "mdb_postgres" {

  dynamic "user" {
    for_each = var.users
    content {
      name       = user.value.name
      password   = user.value.password == "" || user.value.password == null ? random_password.pwd[user.key].result : user.value.password
    }
  }
}
```

Note the way to access the value of random password now is with `user.key` in `random_password.pwd[user.key].result`.

Comment: Man, you're just beautiful) The solution is what I needed) Thank you!

Comment: Haha, I might be beautiful, but Terraform is more beautiful. :D